# How to make Tkinter display an image in a function

Tags: python, image, function, tkinter

I am writing a longer program on a blackjack game, but there is one function that I am trying to make that I am having a hard time with. I am trying to write a function where when called, it will display an image. But when run, it will not display the image. But, if I run the same code outside of the function, it will display the image. Why will it not display the image when the function is called? Thank you,

George

```
import tkinter


def show_image(frame):
    photo2 = tkinter.PhotoImage(file='cards/back.png')
    tkinter.Label(mainWindow, image=photo2).pack(side='left')


mainWindow = tkinter.Tk()
mainWindow.geometry('640x480')
mainWindow.configure(bg='green')

photo = tkinter.PhotoImage(file='cards/back.png')
tkinter.Label(mainWindow, image=photo).pack(side='left')

show_image(mainWindow)

mainWindow.mainloop()
```